# How to import an iCal Feed

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I'd like to import an iCal feed. Every calendar entry on a given URL should be transformed into a node.

I read that this should be possible with with the [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) and [calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) module. But I did not find any description about the topic.

I would be very happy if some one could shed some light on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This online video got me a good bit of the way along:

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode34

> On this podcast, Bob shows how to import any iCal feed of events into your Drupal site and displaying them in a Views-driven calendar on your site. (This means importing your Google or Yahoo! calendars or any other calendar system that puts out a feed in iCal format) This is tasty stuff! Want to have the Drupal calendar delete nodes once they're deleted from the feed? Check out this patch and give it a try. Episode Links Feed API, iCal Parser, Feed API Mapper

I am stuck on populating the Organic Group field of the newly created node.